# SQL Server column inheritance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to make a column inherit its values from another identity column  in the same table?

Update

I have an identity column `ID` and another column `Code`. I want the `code` to be editable with a primary inherited value from `ID` column.

Comment: Can you explain with some data sample, please?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Provide example of your data and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify a computed column (optionally, persisted) based on the value of your identity column. Example:

```
create table IdentityTest
(
    PkId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    SomeInfo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    OtherColumn AS PkId + 1 PERSISTED
)

insert into IdentityTest (SomeInfo)
values ('etc')

select * from IdentityTest
-- this returned:
-- 1    etc     2
```

Of course, there are some limitations/restrictions, as specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300(v=sql.120).aspx).

[EDIT]
Based on extra details provided by OP, computed column can have a VARCHAR type. Example:

```
create table IdentityTest
(
    PkId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    SomeInfo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Code AS 'Code ' + CAST((PkId + 1) AS VARCHAR(32)) PERSISTED
)
```

Comment: does the OtherColumn type set to be int or can I specify the type

Comment: Computed columns type is inferred when evaluating the expression. For example you could obtain a VARCHAR expression like the folowing: `OtherColumn AS CAST((PkId + 1) AS VARCHAR(32)) + ' - etc' PERSISTED`. Persisted is not required, but it allows to put an index to increase the performance of your queries. Of course, at the cost of extra space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I may not have understood the question very well, but if you mean refreshing a value in the entire table, could you not just use UPDATE?

Example:

```
UPDATE Persons
SET Age='34'
WHERE Name='John Smith';
```

But if you mean copying everything from one column to another, UPDATE would also work:

```
UPDATE secondTable
SET secondTable = firstTable
```